# When is $d^{2} x$ =0?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

We want to find $d^{2} z$ :
$$
(4 x-3 z-16) d x+(8 y-24) d y+(6 z-3 x+27) d z =0
$$

So, in my book, we apply the differential operator d to the above equation :

We use the product rule ;

$$
(4 d x-3 d z) d x+(8 d y) d y+(6 d z-3 d x) d z+(6 z-3 x+27) d^{2} z=0
$$

So my question is :

Where did $d^{2} x$ and $d^{2} y$ go?

Are they equal to 0?

If so why
$d^{2} z$ is not 0?

Edit:
That's the problem :

So above $d^{2} z$ isn't asked in the question but it's needed to find the asked ones ;

Problem 1 (65 points)

We consider the function
$$
F(x, y, z)=2 x^{2}+4 y^{2}+3 z^{2}-3 x z-16 x-24 y+27 z+94
$$
and let $z=z(x, y)$ be an implicit function defined by the equality $F(x, y, z)=-1$.

1.1. Calculate $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial^{2} z}{\partial x^{2}}, \frac{\partial^{2} z}{\partial y^{2}}$ and $\frac{\partial^{2} z}{\partial x \partial y}$ at point $(x=1, y=3, z=-5)$.

Comment: What is the context here ? Can we have the total exercice or at least the statement ? With the informations you gave, I would say that $d^2 x=d^2 y=d^2 z=0$ since we deal with [Chain Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_complex)

Comment: I've added the context, and I don't think we studied the chain complex in our classes if that helps

Comment: The book actually describes "the differential operator" $d$ in the context of partial derivatives? Probably there are ways to do something consistent here, but to me it seems more like a way to get confused and get to incorrect conclusions.

Comment: @aschepler - any thoughts why d^2 x is 0?

Comment: In my opinion, at this level of calculus, $d^2 x$ doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Hmm it's calculus 2, so when it's used calc 3?

Comment: I'm not sure I see why you need $d^2z$ to answer Question $1$. Aren't these just simple first and second partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes indeed but my professor used d^2 z as a second method on how to do it

Answer (score 4):

With the context, you have $d^2 x=d^2y=0$, but $d^2 z$ has to be seen as $d^2 z(x,y)$, so that it's not $0$. Here,
$$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$$
and thus
$$d^2 z =\left(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}dx
+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial x}dy\right)dx+\left(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}dx
+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}dy\right)dy.$$

Comment: But i didn't understand why $d^{2} x$ and $d^{2} y$ are zero, how did you conclude that from the context?

Comment: So when do we consider $d^{2} x$ and $d^{2} y$ are zero? In what context?

Comment: It comes from the antisymetry of the wedge product but that is probably not an answer that will convices you. 
If you look at my formula taking $z$ equal to the function $(x,y)\mapsto x$, you have all the partial derivatives equal to $0$ so that $d^2 x =0$

Comment: So is it always 0? Except of course if they are asking for z=f(x, y) like d^2 z here

Comment: You're inventing nonstandard notation here. We do not write $\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial^2 x}$ (for very good reasons).

Comment: @TedShifrin, yeah I've noticed and the last factor i guess it should be multiplied by dy not dx, so I assume they are typos

Comment: I fixed the $dy$ and the second partial derivatives, sorry for the typos.

Comment: @SacAndSac, I guess I've understood but i've tried to derive your d^2 formula and i've arrived to $\frac{\partial(d x)}{\partial x}$, so do i consider it 0 also and why?!

Comment: You don't have such things. Start with the formula $$df =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy.$$ Using linearity of $d$, you have in general (when derivatives have sense)
$$d^2 f =\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}dx
+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}dy\right)dx+\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}dx
+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}dy\right)dy.$$
Now take $f$ defined by $f(x,y)=x$, all the second partial derivatives are $0$ so that $d^2 x$ is $0$.

Comment: Okay thanks appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to use the product rule.  If I have $d(8q\,dq)$, then the resulting differential will be $8\,dq^2 + 8q\,d^2q$.

$$ d\left((4 x-3 z-16)\, dx +(8 y-24)\, dy +(6 z-3 x+27) \,dz\right) =d( 0) $$

This yields

$$ (4x\,dx - 3z\,dz)\,dx + (4 x-3 z-16)\,d^2x + (8\,dy)\,dy + (8y-24)\,d^2y + (6\,dz - 3\,dx)\,dz + (6 z-3 x+27 )d^2z$$

Now, this only makes sense if you use the algebraically-manipulable version of the second derivate.  In this, the second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ is:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$$

This is described more fully in my paper, "[Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials](https://www.academia.edu/37619039/Extending_the_Algebraic_Manipulability_of_Differentials)".

Comment: I don't see how that will help, can you please elaborate?

Comment: It doesn't help you solve the problem, but it helps you see why $d^2x$ and $d^2y$ are zero.  The fact is - they aren't!  Instead, they are just *ignored* in the typical notation.  But, a more expansive notation that takes all differentials into account does include them.

The "typical" notation is not algebraically manipulable (i.e., can't successfully multiply freely by differentials), while the expanded notation is.

Answer (score 0):

I think that part of the misunderstanding of some people is that you need to say what the notation of $dz$ means. I don't recommend solving these problems using that if you are not very familiar with it (otherwise, see SacAndSac's answer).

In any case, to solve the problem you can always take the partial derivatives of the equality $$F\big(x,y,z(x,y)\big)=2x^2+4y^2+3z^2−3xz−16x−24y+27z+94=-1$$ and compute what you want.

To compute $\partial z / \partial x$ take the partial derivative $\partial/\partial z$ in the equality $F(x,y,z)=-1$, but remember that $z$ is a function that depends on $x$ and $y$: $z=z(x,y)$.
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=4x+0+6z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}−3z-3x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}−16+0+27\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+0=0.$$
Now you simply use the extra data of the point where you are asked to compute the derivatives, in this case $(x,y,z)=(1,3,-5)$.
$$4·1+6·(-5)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}−3·(-5)-3·1\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}−16+27\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0.$$
Isolate the derivative and you are done:
$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{4+15-16}{-30-3+27}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

You can do the same for the remaining partial derivatives of $z$.